# Unable to create Component in Web 8 from right-click menu on Folder

Tags: web8, cme

We are not able to create Components when right-clicking on Folders after upgrading from SDL 2013 SP1 HR1 to SDL Web 8.

[image]

I am able to create using the Top menu and the right side panel, but not when I right-click on the folder from the left panel.

[image]

Is this by design in the new version, an issue with our upgrade, or a defect?

Comment: Do you have appropriate rights to create component in this publication?

Comment: Yes , I am an administrator and i am able to create components in right side panel and using top menu.

Comment: Looks like it was a functional choice, since the option doesn't show up at all. I _guess_ because you can't see components on the left side anyway.

Comment: thanks for you answer but this used to be available while we were using Tridion 2011 SP1, 2013 SP1.

Comment: Please verify the editor.config file tridion namespace.

Comment: Please  clear browser cache and try.